# Does Froyo include full Hebrew support for all devices?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, languages, hebrew

I was under the impression that Froyo includes full built-in Hebrew support for all models.

I'm looking into buying a Samsung Galaxy S, and I called up a store about it. At the store they said that if I wanted it with Hebrew support, I would have to add about $75, since Froyo includes Hebrew only for some HTC devices.

Is this true or are they trying to fleece me?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/989/is-hebrew-support-built-into-android

Comment: Sounds fishy to me. What are they going to give you for that $75?

Answer (score 3):

They [are](http://iandroid.co.il/tinman/2011/01/17/%D7%94%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA/) trying to fleece you. Do **not** agree to that, nor to the other tricks they employ trying to fork more money from you (the basic color is not in stock etc.)

Comment: I agree with this.

Answer (score 1):

Can't answer for Galaxy S, but it works on my LG Optimus T. One approach might be to go to the store and try the built-in browser on a web page with Hebrew. As long as that works, I suspect you'll be OK.

Perhaps they will say that for $75 you also get a Hebrew onscreen keyboard... but if so, you could probably skip that and try "Any Soft Keyboard" with the "Hebrew Language Pack", both free in the Market. Again I have not tried anything on a Galaxy S but it works on my Froyo-bearing LG.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a look on my UK Froyo Galaxy S, if I go into the Locale and Text menu, I can't see any options for Hebrew in there, and looking at keyboard settings I can't see any Hebrew options for input language on the Swype or Samsung keyboards either.

Looking at first party Google apps on the Market I see IMEs for Pinyin (Chinese) and Korean, nothing for Hebrew.

However I'm using a device with a European build on it, which would explain why I see mainly European languages in the list, I don't know if other builds will have Hebrew in by default.