# How to install Hebrew on a Samsung galaxy s vibrant

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, languages, hebrew

We have a Samsung Galaxy S vibrant, bought in the US from T-mobile. It's unable to read text messages in Hebrew, write in Hebrew, or anything else. We tried to install the language through the languages section in the settings, but we couldn't find an option for Hebrew. We tried to install a language pack through the market, but it didn't work.

How can we install full support for Hebrew?

The phone is Samsung Galaxy S vibrant, bought from T mobile in USA (NYC).
firmware version is 2.1 with update 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you root your Vibrant, you should be able to get Hebrew characters support, as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/wiki/InstallFonts). Basically you are just overwriting a system default "fall-back" font with the one that has Hebrew.  This will get your phone to recognize the incoming text.  Next you can install a virtual keyboard with a language pack, such as [AnysoftKeyboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard) and the [Hebrew](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.anysoftkeyboard.languagepack.hebrew) language pack.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I don't think you can. It looks like Samsung hasn't released a Hebrew version. See this related question: [Does Froyo include full Hebrew support for all devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3195/does-froyo-include-full-hebrew-support-for-all-devices) as well as [Is Hebrew support built into Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/989/is-hebrew-support-built-into-android)