# Is Hebrew support built into ICS 4.0?

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, languages, localization

Need your help before purchase of tablet Asus T300 with ICS 4.0 in USA.
Will I need to put some updates in order to use Hebrew web pages or use hebrew keybord ?

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/989

Comment: If you can share a link to a Hebrew website I can check if it works. There're keyboards available in the market for almost all languages - there must be several for Hebrew too.

Answer (score 2):

Hebrew is supported in Android 4.0 (it's there since Android 2.2 Froyo).
You can use it as:
- System language
- Keyboard input language (you can set more than one keyboard to quickly toggle it during use by long pressing 'space' when more than one keyboard setting is active)

Actually, this question has been asked before some time ago:

[Is Hebrew support built into Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/989/is-hebrew-support-built-into-android)